# Recycler View edit mode needs to implement two itemClickListener in the same itemview: one for each mode's state

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, android-viewholder

I have an activity which contain a recycler view, in this activity is implemented the edit mode like a lot of applications. everythings works well but I have some performance issue and i'am tryng to goes more deep in the pest practices.

User goes in edit mode by select a menuItem in the toolbar which is placed in the activity, so in the menuItemClickListener in the activity I call a method of the adapter which is used to tell him that user want to go in edit mode:

```
mAdapter.setEditMode(true);
```

then in the adapter:

```
public void setEditMode(boolean editMode){
    this.editMode = editMode;
    notifyDataSetChanged(); //in order to change the items layout
}
```

Now the most difficult part: I need to change the itemClickListener when the editMode variable is set to true, so the listener associated with the holder's itemView change dinamically. I am doing this think in onBindViewHolder so I can set the right listener when the edit mode variable change.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder,int position) {
    if(editMode){
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(listener1);
    }
    else{
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(listener2);
    }
}
```

this solution works but I know that placing a listener inside onBindViewHolder method is a bad practice so I would like to find a solution that allows to implement the listener in the viewHolder constructor.
This is not simple because when the editMode variable is changing the viewHolder constructor is not being called, so he can't set the right listener.
are there any best practice to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After scouring various StackOverFlow answers regarding the most optimum location for a clickListener, people seem to be divided across multiple implementations. Here is what I know for adding a listener in the ViewHolder.

**1. Adapter**:
In your Adapter, override the `onCreateViewHolder()` method

```
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) 
{
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(//pass in your args);
     ImageView imageview1 = //init your views
    TextView textView = //init your views
    return new MyViewHolder(view, textView);
}
```

**2. Viewholder**:
When you create your Viewholder class, allow it to implement `View.OnClickListener` and override the `onClick` method there.

```
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
  public ImageView imageView1;

  private MyViewHolder(View itemView, ImageView imageView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageView1 = imageView;
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
        //Implement your click functionality here
  }
}
```